# undefined method `fql_query' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-fql, koala

With the koala gem I am trying to count checkins for a page. I am using rails.

In my `user.rb` I have a method for getting a new connection to the Facebook graph:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def facebook
     @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
 end
end
```

In my school.rb I have a method for counting the checkins:

```
class school < ActiveRecord::Base
 def count_checkins(name)
  checkins = @facebook.fql_query("SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = #{name}")
 end
end
```

And I am calling it from the view like this:

```
<%= @school.count_checkins(@school.name) %>
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined method `fql_query' for nil:NilClass
```

Dont really understand why I get this error, any help would be wonderful.

Comment: where is @facebook assigned inside school.rb?

Comment: @AustinMullins I am using it for another method in school.rb, Cant I use it outside the school class?

Comment: I don't think so, though I'll admit I'm not an expert in all the magic that is Rails. Based on normal OOP principals, I'd your school model needs to create a User object and call its facebook method before calling fql_query on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't actually created the `@facebook` object inside your School model. We'd need to see the rest of your school.rb file to know for sure.  I'd suggest you create the object inside your School.initialize() method like so:

```
def initialize(oauth_token)
  unless oauth_token.nil?
    @facebook = Koala::facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  end
end
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to pass the desired `oauth_token` to your `School.new()` call. Then you'll have one `@facebook` object for each `School`.

### Edit

After looking at the [gist](http://gist.github.com/4582873), I realized that you had actually intantiated a `User` object, and called the facebook method on that. That is actually the better way to do it. The problem is, you're using `@current_user`, which would have to be setup as a property of the `school` model. You probably meant to use the helper function `current_user` instead.

```
 def count_checkins(name)
  u = current_user
  u.@facebook.fql_query("SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = #{name}")
 end
```

Try that and see what happens. At the very least, you should get a different error message.

### Edit 2

So, now I'm thinking the `current_user` function should be called in controller code, not model code. This is because the current user is something that doesn't really exist except as part of an active request. Therefore, we should take `User u` as a parameter to the `count_checkins` function like so:

```
def count_checkins(name, u)
  u.facebook.fql_query("SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = #{name}")
end
```

You'll need to change the code where you call `count_checkins()` too:

```
count_checkins(name, current_user)
```

That should do it. Let's see!

Comment: From where should I call the this method, from user.rb?

Comment: ok, that's making me think the `current_user` helper function isn't in scope inside the School class.  I use that with Devise in my app that I'm working on, but I only call it inside controller code, not the models. I'm not sure which way is more the "Rails way". In any case, you'll have to either instantiate a @current_user object inside your model or link up a current_user helper function to define your count_checkins function this way.

Comment: Almost there, I get this error right now: undefined method `facebook' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I'm still thinking `current_user` isn't working right. I've only ever used it inside a controller before, and the one I have right now is defined by the Devise gem. I've seen examples of a roll-your-own current_user function, but I'm not sure that's what you want to do here. What if you passed in the current user as a parameter to the `count_checkins()` method? That way you could call `current_user` in the controller instead of the model.

Comment: Oh man, I just missed your update when I left the computer this morning. Sorry to keep you waiting all day. Where are you making the function call?

Comment: So, I've made an assumption above that there was a User object created in the controller like `@user = current_user`, and then in the view you should be able to call `@school.count_checkins(name, @user)`. I'm sorry there's such a lag in our correspondence, I'm pretty sure we're close on this one now.

Comment: I still get undefined method `facebook' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ok, so `current_user` works, but it's returning "nil", which means no user is logged in. Does your controller have a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` statement before the method definitions?

Comment: So I have logged the user in, now I get this error: OAuthException: (#601) Parser error: unexpected '? at position 43 , so something is wrong with my sql query. I have tried this statment throw the facebook graph and it works

Comment: So I have changed the query to somehthing like this:  u.facebook.fql_query('SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = "' + name + '"') And It works but it return a hash data, it return this: [{"checkins"=>10}]

Comment: So I did something like this: return b = a[0]["checkins"] and it workt!